# Animate element position swap in Angular

Tags: angular, css-animations

I want to animate s.th. with Angulars Animation Module or CSS

I have a dynamic list of cards in my component. 
These cards should be swapped depending on how the array contains them.
A button can change the array content (changes the ordering of the elements).

Angular Animations mostly use ease-in/ease-out but in my case it's just a positional change (swap). 
The element should still stay there.
Here is a short example to illustrate what I mean:

```
[STATE 1]
[--- ELEMENT A ---]     [--- ELEMENT Z ---]
[--- ELEMENT B ---]     [--- ELEMENT Y ---]
[--- ELEMENT C ---]     [--- ELEMENT X ---]
[--- ELEMENT D ---]     [--- ELEMENT W ---]
[--- ELEMENT E ---]     [--- ELEMENT V ---]
[--- ELEMENT F ---]     [--- ELEMENT U ---]
```

After I click a button it should animate how it moved.
In this example Element V swap place with Element A

```
[STATE 2]
[--- ELEMENT V ---]     [--- ELEMENT Z ---]
[--- ELEMENT B ---]     [--- ELEMENT Y ---]
[--- ELEMENT C ---]     [--- ELEMENT X ---]
[--- ELEMENT D ---]     [--- ELEMENT W ---]
[--- ELEMENT E ---]     [--- ELEMENT A ---]
[--- ELEMENT F ---]     [--- ELEMENT U ---]
```

Is there a proper way to do this with angular?
Or do I really need to interact with the DOM so I can use absolute positioning and css translate function?

I have updated the question with a stackblitz example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5mstrg

This probably sums up the problem im facing. I know already which elements I want to change in TypeScript (the data).

But for the animations I need to know where it is in the DOM (for translateX- function).

My goal is to see the swap from Box1 to Box2 and vice versa via animation. (Slowly moving the character there)

Comment: You'll need to use animation parameters. Where you pass the start and end positions for the animation. https://angular.io/api/animations/animation

Comment: You'll need to actually try to get it working, and then update the question with what you've tried. We can't write the source code for you.

Comment: I have updated the question.